# Logging to stream

Tags: c#, logging, enterprise-library

Is there an existing trace listener for enterprise library that could be used to write to a stream...such as a udp stream?  Or would I need to create a custom trace listener?

The idea for this came up in an Eclipse project with a legacy application.  The only options the current project had was to log to the screen, or log to a rolling file.  Logging to the screen was a pain and caused invalid html.  Logging to the file was fine...but refreshing the file got old...It seems like it could be useful to have an option to log to a udp server console so you can info 'dumped' in real time.

Comment: log4net can be configured for UDP http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html   I use rolling-daily files typically.

Comment: Do you only have one logfile?  Can you just run `tail -f`?  http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/

Comment: notepad++ will ask you to reload the file every time it detects that the underlying file has changed.  I use that with rolling-daily files.

Comment: @Tuzo - Good idea. That would work for the Eclipse project

Answer (score 0):

Log4net has a UDP appender. You can find more information [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_UdpAppender.htm)